# selectively accept HTML tags in user submitted string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I would like to do is giving to my user the ability to format a submitted text with simple tags such as `<b></b> <i></i>` ...

Though I cannot really mark the submitted string as `html_safe` as I don't really want the user to use any html tag they want.

I was wondering if there was a simple solution. (I am pretty new to Ruby and cannot really set up a parsing method by myself)

Ideally it would be a very simple customisable CKeditor-ish gem  or alternatively some Ruby code to parse the string, keep the accepted tags and remove every other tag. (then my string can be marked `html_safe`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `sanitize` helper method which is built into rails.

```
<%= sanitize @user_input, tags: %w(b i) %>
```

It whitelists the allowed tags. Any tags not in the `tags:` array are not rendered.

Read about it here...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: Ruby is amazaing, couldn't imagine something more concise than this ^^